# Question related to diagonally dominant matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

A matrix is said to be positive if each entry in the matrix is positive.
If $A$ is real, irreducible, diagonally dominant (or strictly dominant matrix) and has positive diagonal and non-positive off-diagonal elements. Then how to show that inverse of $A$ exists and is positive.?

I am able to show that inverse of $A$ exists, but don't know how to prove that it is positive.

Comment: what do you mean by positive matrix ? do you know hadamard lemma ?

Comment: Here positive matrix is a square matrix whose all entries are positive.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure your problem is formulated correctly. Consider $\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & -1  \\
-1 & 1 \end{array} \right)$.

Comment: I have edited my question. Earlier, I wrote wrong definiiton of diagonally dominant matrix. I am sorry. Thank a lot for correcting me.

Comment: I believe this counterexample still holds for the definition of diagonally dominant matrix given at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix

Comment: But this is for irreducible diagonally dominant matrix which is equivalent to  strictly diagonally dominant matrix.

Comment: It seems that the definition comes from the fact that the terms "irreducible and diagonally dominant" and "irreducibly diagonal dominant" are not always consistent. In my brief review of related articles (which I'm sure you have seen) the latter seems to refer to the case where at least one of the inequalities is strict.