# irreducible, diagonally dominant matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am facing a problem for irreducible,diagonally dominant matrices. How to prove that irreducible, diagonally dominant matrix is invertible? Please help me in this problem.

Comment: Could you define the terms you're using? I'm confused about how this question is different from the question you said you already knew how to solve here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370502/

Comment: I was able to show that strictly diagonally dominant matrix is invertible,but don't know how to prove that irreducible diagonally dominant  matrix is invertible.

Answer (score 1):

They are not necessarily invertible. The easiest counterexample is $\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&1}$.

Comment: This is not the usual definition of irreducibly diagonally dominant, in which the matrix needs to satisfy (i) irreducibility, (ii) (weak) diagonal dominance in all rows, and (iii) strict diagonal dominance in at least one row. You missed (iii).

Comment: @par You are reading between the lines, I guess? The OP says "*irreducible,* diagonally dominant matrix", not "*irreducibly* diagonally dominant matrix". He/she even cared to add a comma between "irreducible" and "diagonally dominant".

Comment: Fair enough; you are correct. Perhaps you can edit your answer to point this out explicitly so I can remove my downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it's invertible, if you want the proof check this PDF

http://citron.9grid.fr/docs/gerschgorin.pdf

Comment: Hi: welcome to math.SE. While this answer is helpful, it's usually a better idea to add some content to outline the proof (along with the link). Links can rot, and you are likely to get more votes if you spruce up this solution :)